# Bash: How do I truncate an array?

Tags: linux, arrays, bash

I'd like to change the value of an array and would appreciate any help.

I got an array like this:

```
users=(root isometric akau)
```

(This is actually a list of current users) that I'd like to be able to test if the user exists and if they do not, then to remove the person from the array.  I've tried experiment with this by putting it in a for loop and evaluating it:

```
for i in ${users[@]}; do
  eval "users=($([ -z $(grep \"^\$i\" /etc/shadow) ] && sed \"s/\$i//g\"))"
done

echo $users
```

I thought about playing with this some more but I thought I might be getting too complicated (I'm not sure I can put a command in an array).  Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

*Edit:*

How I entered the array variable unset number:

```
cnt=0
for i in ${users[@]}; do
  [ -z "$(grep "^$i" /etc/shadow)" ] && unset users[cnt] || ((cnt++))
done
```

*Edit2:*

Actually Dennis's is even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may not need a `for` loop. Try this:

```
users=(root isometric akau)
list="${users[@]/%/|}"      # convert array to list, add pipe char after each user
# strip the spaces from the list and look for usernames between the beg. of the line
# and the end of the word, make an array out of the result
users=($(grep -Eo "^(${list// })\>" /etc/shadow))
```

The `grep`, unraveled, would look like this:

```
grep -Eo "^(root|isometric|akau|)\>" /etc/shadow
```

Comment: Very clever. I'd give it plus 2 for ingenuity if at all possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

So if you have...

```
$ users=(root isometric akau)
$ echo ${users[*]}
root isometric akau
```

All you need to do is, say:

```
$ unset users[1]
```

And then...

```
$ echo ${users[*]}
root akau
$
```

Comment: Haha, nice.  Much better.  Thanks DR.  Just for reference, I'll put how to discover the number of the of the array value in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `jane` from `users`:

```
users=(john joe mary jane liz root foobar)

for ((i = 0; i < ${#users[@]}; ++i)); do
    [[ ${users[i]} == jane ]] && break
done

users=(${users[@]:0:i} ${users[@]:i+1})

echo "${users[@]}" #=> john joe mary liz root foobar
```

The general principle is that there is no array slice in bash (obviously); you have to recreate the array without the excluded element(s).

That said, there are numerous ways to do what your are looking for in a for(in) loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
users=(root nobody akau)
declare -a shadowusers
declare -a notinshadow
i=0
while IFS=":" read -r user b c d e f g h
do
    shadowusers[$i]=$user
    i=$((i+1))
done < "/etc/shadow"
for u in ${users[@]}
do
    found=0
    for s in ${shadowusers[@]}
    do
           case "$u" in
               "$s") found=1;;
           esac   
    done
    [ "$found" -eq 0 ] && notinshadow[$j]=$u
    j=$((j+1)) 
done 
echo ${notinshadow[@]}
```

Comment: +1 for creativity.  Never thought to redirect to a while loop before... huh.